# Thread does not terminate when Window is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I have a class named `Manager` which has a thread. When the application is closed I want to find all instances of `Manager` to abort their threads. How can I do that?

I already tried `Unloaded` event in its `UserControl` but it only works when the `UserControl` is closed not the whole application.

Now I want to use `Closed` event of its `Window` but I don't want to have a `Manager` reference there. Any idea?

Comment: Does the manager class have a reference to the thread it runs in? If not, how would you find the thread which belongs to the manager? Do you use the thread pool? If so, there might be more manager than threads. Generally: objects are in memory and code is in threads. And they needn't have anything in common.

Comment: `Any idea?` - Yes. Delete all your code immediately and start all over making sure you honor the Separation of Concerns principle. The UI is not the right place to "start threads", and a `UserControl` does not "have a thread" (whatever that means). Create a proper ViewModel and manage whatever threading required at the ViewModel level.

Comment: Yes it has a reference. I didn't use a thread pool because I needed priority for my tasks.

Comment: @HighCore. My userControl is not aware of the thread. Some VM inside uc has a Manager which has a thread.

Comment: @Bizz in that case you should also manage the (graceful) termination of these threads at the ViewModel level, and the UI doesn't have anything to do with that. Please edit your question and add relevant code, and remove the part about the `UserControl`, which is not relevant to the question if you're dealing with a ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the threads IsBackground property to true, it won't hold up the app terminating on exit

Answer (score 2):

Make the threads a background thread and it will terminate automatically when the program ends. You can set the type of thread via the [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property.

However, I don't consider this as a clean solution. It's cleaner to use a `while(!terminate) { ... }` loop so that the single threads can finish their tasks, e.g. write into a file. If you just terminate the thread which writes into a file you might end up with corrupt files. This does not only apply to files but other items as well.

Comment: I think terminating this thread won't corrupt anything. but I keep that in mind. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IDisposable` in your Manager class and ensure that you close and deallocate any resources, such as `Threads`, in the `Dispose` method. This will be called when the garbage collector gets around to cleaning up after your application closes, provided you've followed the normal IDisposable pattern as found here:

```
public class ComplexResourceHolder : IDisposable {

    private IntPtr buffer; // unmanaged memory buffer
    private SafeHandle resource; // disposable handle to a resource

    public ComplexResourceHolder(){
        this.buffer = ... // allocates memory
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
            ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory
        if (disposing){ // release other disposable objects
            if (resource!= null) resource.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~ ComplexResourceHolder(){
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although using IsBackground property would work, to perform additional cleanup, you can use some static members on the Manager class to keep track of the running threads, and loop on that collection when the app exits.

Answer (score 1):

Please take the other answers and comments as a reason to refactor your code and create another solution. However if you have some reason to commit to this, you can create a static list that holds instances to each Manager that can be aborted on exit:

```
class Manager
{
    //A WeakReference prevents memory leaks when you dispose of managers in another place
    private static readonly List<WeakReference<Manager>> Instances 
             = new List<WeakReference<Manager>>();

    public static void AbortAll()
    {
        foreach (var weakReference in Instances)
        {
            Manager current;
            if (weakReference.TryGetTarget(out current))
                current.Abort();
        }
        Instances.Clear();
    }

    private void Abort()
    {
        //...
    }

    public Manager()
    {
        //...
        Instances.Add(new WeakReference<Manager>(this));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Manager a = new Manager();
Manager b = new Manager();

Manager.AbortAll(); //calls abort on a and b
```